# How to Union Multiple Tables with same column names on Google Big Query?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to create a union with 3 tables that have the same column names. However, the queries tested seems not to be working.

The first query that I have used is the following:

Select *  FROM `table1`
UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM `table2`

SELECT *  FROM `table3`
UNION ALL

The second query used is the following:

SELECT *
FROM
(select * from `table_1`),
(select * from `table_2`),
(select * from `table_3`)

Both of them are not working for me. Please someone can help me with this?

Comment: One thing you may want to validate is that the schema's for each table occur in the same order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if columns are identical:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table3
```